# how to re-enable a disabled trap

Tags: bash

I enabled a trap DEBUG with

```
function my_trap ()
{
    # some code in here
}
trap 'my_trap' DEBUG
```

then I needed to disable it for a while, so I did

```
trap - DEBUG
```

**now**:

how can I re-enable the same trap?
.. without rewriting:

```
trap 'my_trap' DEBUG
```

I don't want to re-write this because if I ever change the trap function name, I'll need to change it only in one point.

Answer (score 2):

I've only found the following way:

```
traps=$( trap )
declare regex="'([^']+)' DEBUG"
[[ ${traps} =~ ${regex} ]]
trap "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" DEBUG
```

Is there any more elegant one?